# Edit a text file using php

Tags: php, file

I download a file and now need to replace few strings with my own string. I am able to

replace them... but how can i make the changes permanent...???

But the file i download is a html file.

Comment: remove old file then create a new one with the same name

Comment: @Dalen: I need to replace few links in that file with my own. So how do i store the inbetween text?

Comment: Permanent on the server? Upload the changed file and replace the original on the server with the uploaded.

Comment: @rik: yep... but how do i store the text in between?

Comment: the steps would be: - read the file (into a string) - compute the string - store the string into a file

Comment: @Dalen: thanx...that seems to be nice...!!!

Comment: @Kuttu: Download, edit, upload and save the whole file. No chunks, no "in between".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). Make sure the file or directory you write to is writable.

Comment: i can do that only for the replaced text, I suppose. What about other text?

Comment: @Kuttu: post your code. without it it's very hard to understand what you're actually doing.